# Get full match instead of capturing group

Tags: java, regex

Say there is a string:

```
16 NIP 712-10-08-323 2020
```

I'd like to have a full match what comes after `NIP` until first character different from `[0-9-]`. So I'd like my full match be
`712-10-08-323`. I've come up with the following regex, but it matches `NIP 712-10-08-323` instead of `712-10-08-323`.

[(?:NIP )[0-9-]{13}](https://regex101.com/r/b5KSqk/1)

Comment: Use [`NIP\s+([0-9-]{13})`](https://regex101.com/r/b5KSqk/2) and grab `matcher.group(1)` value

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The thing is that I do not want use groups.

Comment: Then use `(?<=NIP\s)[0-9-]{13}`, but it is not the best if whitespace number can differ between `NIP` and the digits. I adjusted the close reason.

Comment: Thanks, that's it.